# A Generic Error occurred in GDI+ Saving Picturebox into ole database

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I'm trying to save a picturebox into an ole database.

Here's my code :

```
Dim stream As New IO.MemoryStream
PictureBox1.Image.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Try
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Guestinfo ([GuestName],[Phone],[Idofguest],[Room],[Arrival],[Checkout],[Address],[IDImage]) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "',(@IDImage))"
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand

    With command
        .CommandText = query
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", stream.GetBuffer())
        .Connection = conn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    MsgBox("Saved Successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    conn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

In "A Generic Error occurred in GDI+" this error appear:

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

By the way, my column type is Ole Object.
I hope someone help me ...

Comment: There are several problems with that code, is there an image assigned to the PicBox?  You also should dispose of the MemStream, you need to reset the stream.Positiom before trying to read from it, use ToArray not GetBuffer and use SQL Parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Comment: Yes, there is an image assigned to the picbox, and for the dispose and reset i've just added it now.

Comment: i wish for more help @Plutonix

Answer (score 0):

This application has an Open Button which will help you open any picture file to a PictureBox on the form using OpenFileDialog. You will see the path of the picture file in a disabled TextBox. When you click the update button the Picture's path is saved to an Access Database.

Follow the steps below to create a similar project for yourself:
* Create a new Visual Basic.net project. Select Windows Forms Application from New Project Dialog Box. Name this application whatever you want.
* Create the following with below mentioned properties:
 - Form - (Name): sample, Text: FormPictureApplication
 - PictureBox - (Name): PictureBox1, SizeMode: StretchImage
 - Button - (Name): ButtonUpdate, Text: &Update
 - Button - (Name): ButtonOpen, Text: &Open
 - TextBox - (Name): TextBoxPictureFilePath, Enabled: False

- Double Click the Form, insert the following code right above Public Class {...}:

  Imports System.Data.OleDb 
  Imports System.IO 
  Imports Microsoft.Win32

  Double Click ButtonOpen and insert the following code:

  Dim img As String

  Dim myStream As Stream = Nothing 
  Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()

  openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\" 
  openFileDialog1.Filter = Nothing 
  openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 
  openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True 
  openFileDialog1.FileName = ""

  If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then 
  Try 
  myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile() 
  If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then

  TextBoxPictureFilePath.Text = ""

  img = openFileDialog1.FileName 
  PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(img)

  TextBoxPictureFilePath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName

  End If 
  Catch Ex As Exception 
  MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message) 
  Finally 
  If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then 
  myStream.Close() 
  End If 
  End Try 
  End If
- Create a Microsoft Access Database in your convenient location and name it as Databasemikeoe2003PictureApplication.mdb
- Create a table with the name Tablemikeoe2003PictureApplication and add following Columns to it:

  Id - Datatype: Autonumber 
  PicturePath - DataType: Memo (as file paths can be considerably long at times)
- Double Click the UpdateButton and insert the following code:

  Try 
  Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection 
  Dim myCommand As OleDbCommand 
  Dim mySQLString As String 
  myConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Databasemikeoe2003PictureApplication.mdb;") 
  myConnection.Open() 
  mySQLString = "INSERT INTO Tablemikeoe2003PictureApplication (PicturePath) VALUES('" & Replace$(TextBoxPictureFilePath.Text, "'", "''") & "')" 
  myCommand = New OleDbCommand(mySQLString, myConnection) 
  myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

  PictureBox1.Image = Nothing 
  TextBoxPictureFilePath.Text = ""

  Catch ex As Exception 
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " - " & ex.Source) 
  End Try
- Run the application, it should work as desired.

Comment: i'm using a scanned image into the picturebox directly by stream.

Comment: It will be so helpfull if you told me how to save that scanned image into the database @CodingSource